# How to protect input negative value in this code?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have the following function, I want to protect input negative number on this function, I want when input negative number it will show negative number not allow. Please help?

```
function fruits(mango, apple, orange){
        var mangoPrice= 50;
        var applePrice= 80;
        var orangePrice= 100;
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        var count= arguments[i];
        
        console.log(typeof 'count');
    
        if(count>=0){
            var totalMangoPrice= mango*mangoPrice;
            var totalApplePrice= apple*applePrice;   
            var totalOrangePrice= orange*orangePrice;
            var total= totalMangoPrice + totalApplePrice + totalOrangePrice;  
        }
        else{
            total= 'negative not allow';
        }
   
   
    };


         return total;


}
// var result= fruits(1, 1 , 1);
```

Comment: BTW `typeof 'count'` will always be a string. You probably want `typeof(count)`.

Comment: "Protect" probably should be "prevent" here?

Comment: You want the function to return `'negative not allow'` if **any** of the argument is a negative number?

Comment: @mdmannon - there are a few quality answers here. If any of them solved your issue, please accept it as the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Look at my modification below. I added these 2 lines which will check all your arguments to find any negative ones. If so, it will exit the function with your message.

```
let hasNegative = Object.values(arguments).some(n => n < 0);
if (hasNegative) return 'negative not allow';
```

```js
function fruits(mango, apple, orange) {
  var mangoPrice = 50;
  var applePrice = 80;
  var orangePrice = 100;

  // add these 2 lines
  let hasNegative = Object.values(arguments).some(n => n < 0);
  if (hasNegative) return 'negative not allow';

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var totalMangoPrice = mango * mangoPrice;
    var totalApplePrice = apple * applePrice;
    var totalOrangePrice = orange * orangePrice;
    var total = totalMangoPrice + totalApplePrice + totalOrangePrice;
  };
  return total;
}
var result = fruits(1, -1, 1);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: clean but I would prefer an early return instead of looping all the args.

Comment: It is an early return. Not sure what you mean

Comment: A early return should be ```if (mango < 0 || apple < 0 || orange < 0) return``` before for loop. your filter function would loop through all args again.

Comment: My suggestion. you can use ```Object.values(arguments).some(n => n < 0)``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fruits(mango, apple, orange) {
  var mangoPrice = 50;
  var applePrice = 80;
  var orangePrice = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] < 0) {
      console.log('Negative inputs not allowed');
      return;
    }
  }
    // or
    if (mango < 0 || apple < 0 || orange < 0) {
      console.log('Negative inputs not allowed');
      return;
    }
    // or-end

    var totalMangoPrice = mango * mangoPrice;
    var totalApplePrice = apple * applePrice;
    var totalOrangePrice = orange * orangePrice;
    var total = totalMangoPrice + totalApplePrice + totalOrangePrice;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: The second option should be put before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking your code, it looks like you are inputting the amount you want of each fruit. Then you are checking that the amount isn't negative.

If it's negative, you are returning an error message.

If they're positive, you are multiplying the amount by their price and returning the total price.

```js
function fruits(mangoAmount, appleAmount, orangeAmount) {
  if (typeof mangoAmount == "number" && typeof appleAmount == "number" && typeof orangeAmount == "number") {
    const mangoPrice = 50;
    const applePrice = 80;
    const orangePrice = 100;
    if (mangoAmount >= 0 && appleAmount >= 0 && orangeAmount) {
      return (mangoPrice * mangoAmount) + (applePrice * appleAmount) + (orangePrice * orangeAmount);
    }
    return "Amounts can not be negative numbers";
  }
  return "Amount have to be of type 'number'"
}

const workingTest = fruits(1, 1, 1);
const stringTest = fruits("1", 1, 1);
const negativeTest = fruits(-1, 1, 1);
console.log({
  workingTest,
  stringTest,
  negativeTest
});
```

The code above is a good improvement however, returning the value like that means that we can't easily handle the error. So instead we return an object that has 3 properties: success, message and value

```js
function fruits(mangoAmount, appleAmount, orangeAmount) {
  if (typeof mangoAmount == "number" && typeof appleAmount == "number" && typeof orangeAmount == "number") {
    const mangoPrice = 50;
    const applePrice = 80;
    const orangePrice = 100;
    if (mangoAmount >= 0 && appleAmount >= 0 && orangeAmount) {
      // here I am putting the values in an array and then using the reduce method to add them all together. I am only doing this to make it easier to read.
      const total = [
        (mangoPrice * mangoAmount),
        (applePrice * appleAmount),
        (orangePrice * orangeAmount)
      ].reduce((a, b) => a + b);

      return {
        success: true,
        message: "",
        value: total,
      };
    }
    return {
      success: false,
      message: "Amounts can not be negative numbers",
      value: 0,
    };
  }
  return {
    success: false,
    message: "Amounts have to be of type 'number'",
    value: 0,
  };
}

const workingTest = fruits(1, 1, 1);
const stringTest = fruits("1", 1, 1);
const negativeTest = fruits(-1, 1, 1);
console.log({
  workingTest,
  stringTest,
  negativeTest
});
```

Now our errors are a lot easier to manage. We can destructor the object and check if the function succeed. Making error handling a lot easier.

Here is an example of a success.

```js
const doTaskSuccess = () => {
  return {
    success: true,
    message: "",
    value: 42,
  }
}

const {success, message, value} = doTaskSuccess();
if(success){
  console.log(value);
} else {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Here is an example of a fail.

```js
const doTaskFail = () => {
  return {
    success: false,
    message: "The task failed.",
    value: 0,
  }
}

const {success, message, value} = doTaskFail();
if(success){
  console.log(value);
} else {
  console.log(message);
}
```

You can see that the error handling code is the same. That's why sending useful objects like this is a lot better for error handling.